# How to pass pointer and pointer to a function?

Tags: c++

I implement a function that acts like getline( .. ). So my initial approach is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

void getstr( char*& str, unsigned len ) {
    char c;
    size_t i = 0;
    while( true ) {
        c = getchar(); // get a character from keyboard
        if( '\n' == c || EOF == c ) { // if encountering 'enter' or 'eof'
            *( str + i ) = '\0'; // put the null terminate
            break; // end while
        }
        *( str + i ) = c;
        if( i == len - 1 ) { // buffer full 
            len = len + len; // double the len 
            str = ( char* )realloc( str, len ); // reallocate memory
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main() {
    const unsigned DEFAULT_SIZE = 4;
    char* str = ( char* )malloc( DEFAULT_SIZE * sizeof( char ) );
    getstr( str, DEFAULT_SIZE );
    printf( str );
    free( str );
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I think I should switch to pure C instead of using half C/C++. So I change char*& to char**:
Pointer to Pointer version ( crahsed )

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

void getstr( char** str, unsigned len ) {
    char c;
    size_t i = 0;
    while( true ) {
        c = getchar(); // get a character from keyboard
        if( '\n' == c || EOF == c ) { // if encountering 'enter' or 'eof'
            *( *str + i ) = '\0'; // put the null terminate
            break; // done input end while
        }
        *( *str + i ) = c;
        if( i == len - 1 ) { // buffer full 
            len = len + len; // double the len 
            *str = ( char* )realloc( str, len ); // reallocate memory
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main() {
    const unsigned DEFAULT_SIZE = 4;
    char* str = ( char* )malloc( DEFAULT_SIZE * sizeof( char ) );
    getstr( &str, DEFAULT_SIZE );
    printf( str );
    free( str );
    return 0;
}
```

But this version crashed, ( access violation ). I tried run the debugger, but I could not find where it crashed. I'm running Visual Studio 2010 so could you guys show me how to fix it?

Another weird thing I've encountered is that, if I leave the "&" out, it only works with Visual Studio, but not g++. That is

```
void getstr( char* str, unsigned len )
```

From my understanding, whenever we use pointer to allocate or deallocate a block of memory, we actually modify where that pointer are pointing to. So I think we have to use either ** or *& to modify the pointer. However, because it run correctly in Visual Studio, is it just luck or it should be ok either way?

Comment: The second part - that it 'works' in VS without the called function modifying the pointer - might be explained if there was space at the end of the originally allocated memory for realloc to use. You'll have to say which version of VS it is to do any more diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks, Pete. This point is really interesting.

Comment: As Fred suggested, using std::string would be easier and safer to work with since you don't have to dick around with reallocating and stuff like that. Is there any reason you're prefering a raw char* over the alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer crash is probably in the realloc

`*str = ( char* )realloc( str, len )`

Should be

`*str = ( char* )realloc( *str, len )`

As Steve points out, your code leaks the original if realloc fails, so maybe change it to something like:

```
char* tmp = (char*) realloc(*str, len)
if (tmp) {
    *str = tmp
} else {
    // realloc failed.. sigh
}
```

Comment: Better to not `realloc` direct into `*str` - this leaks the original if `realloc` fails.

Comment: Hi Steve, so I should put another check if realloc() fail ?

Comment: char* new = (char*)realloc(*str, len);
if(!new) error("Out of memory");
*str = new;

Comment: @Jorgen - I hate naming variables "new"

Comment: @sb Well, since it was C, I figured it would be ok. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Then, I think I should switch to pure C instead of using half C/C++.

I suggest the other direction. Go full-blown C++.

Answer (score 0):

Well, running it in a debugger highlights this line

```
        *str = ( char* )realloc( str, len ); // reallocate memory
```

where there is a mismatch between `str` - the pointer to the variable - and `*str` - the pointer to the memory.

I'd be tempted to rewrite it so it returns the string, or zero on error, rather than having a void return and an in/out parameter ( like fgets does, which seems to be the function you're sort-of copying the behaviour of ). Or wrap such a function. That style doesn't let you get confused as you're only ever dealing with a pointer to char, rather than a pointer to pointer to char.

```
    char* getstr_impl ( char* str, unsigned len ) {...}

    void getstr( char** str, unsigned len ) {
        *str = getstr_impl ( *str, len );
    }
```